Question on convergence of Fourier transform of $f_a(t)=\Gamma(a+i t)$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$
Mathematica indicates the inverse Fourier transform of $F(\omega)=e^{-\omega-e^{-\omega}}$ is
$$f(t)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}\left[e^{-\omega-e^{-\omega}}\right](t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\omega-e^{-\omega}}\, e^{-i t \omega} \, d\omega=\Gamma(1+i t)\tag{1}$$
which implies the Fourier transform of $f(t)=\Gamma(1+i t)$ is
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[\Gamma(1+i t)](\omega)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Gamma(1+i t)\, e^{i \omega t} \, dt=e^{-\omega-e^{-\omega}}\tag{2}.$$

Question: Is there a more general result with respect to the convergence of the Fourier transform of $f_a(t)=\Gamma(a+i t)$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$? In other words, is it known for which values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does the Fourier transform $F_a(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[\Gamma(a+i t)](\omega)$ converge?

Using different Fourier parameters the Fourier transform
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[\Gamma(1+i t)](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Gamma(1+i t)\, e^{-2 \pi i \omega t} \, dt=2 \pi\, e^{2 \pi \omega-e^{2 \pi \omega}}\tag{3}$$
leads to the formula
$$\Gamma(s)=f(-i (s-1))\,,\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{4}$$
where
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{f, N\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=-2 f (2 n-1)}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right)\, F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=-4 f (2 n-1)}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right)\, e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\tag{5}.$$

In formula (5) above $F(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $\Gamma(1+i t)$ defined in formula (3) above, $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, and the evaluation frequency $f$ in the two inner sums over k is assumed to be a positive integer. Formula (5) above is equivalent to formula (5) in my related MSO question which provides information on its derivation.

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (4) for $\Gamma(s)$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Gamma(s)$ where the underlying  formula (5) referenced by formula (4) is evaluated at $f=8$ and $N=10$.

Figure (1): Illustration of formula (4) for $\Gamma(s)$ in orange overlaid on blue reference function $\Gamma(s)$


https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E9 is useful to study the convergence of the Fourier transform.

Assume that $x>0$ and that $N$ is a nonnegative integer.    In a previous answer I argued that  $$e^{-x} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-(a +it)} ,  \Gamma(a +it) , \mathrm dt, \quad a>0,$$  and  $$e^{-x}- \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(-x)^{k}}{k!}  = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-(a+it)} , \Gamma(a +it)  , \mathrm dt, \quad -(N+1) < a < -N.$$  Then it would seem that we just need to replace $x$ with $e^{-\omega}$.
